# media queries for large phones

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using the standard mobile first method for a responsive site which works great for most phones.  my current mobile breakpoint is

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 768px)
```

however, this does not pick up my new turbo 2 or the iphone 6 as both of these phones have screens that register at 980px.

does anyone have a good media query style fix?

Comment: from google search: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Comment: CSS Tricks - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/